# Ability to save unfinished post for later

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

To the Moderators:

Please create the ability to save unfinished posts for finishing up later on. It is difficult to get a detailed answer in a single sitting. I am writing a community wiki atm and this feature would save a lot of headache.

All the best!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of change isn't something that the moderators can do as it lies within the software driving the site.

There are existing facilities to save drafts.  These are described in  [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1177/236563).

If you wish to ask for something better, you could try making a [feature-request](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) on the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).